# General rule to calculate padding

Tags: website-design, layout

Is there a general rule to calculate padding/margin values to make web page layout more err... beautiful? (Spacing between elements on a page, between elements and page borders, etc.)

Comment: No, there is no general rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be more of a graphic design question than UX question. But there's something called "vertical rhythm" that might help in laying out the flow of elements on a page.

Here's some references to get started if you're dealing with webpages:

- http://www.markboulton.co.uk/journal/incremental-leading
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/17/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/
- http://typecast.com/blog/4-simple-steps-to-vertical-rhythm

It treats typography as king when it comes to spacing. Using your base font size, determine the line height required for comfortable reading when you have paragraphs of text. Using that line height, lay out your vertical grid. Then adjust all typography as well as your elements according to that grid.

Try to always fit elements as a multiple (or halves or thirds) unit of your line height. Apply this first for your typographical elements, then extend it to your other elements: forms, containers etc...

Some examples:
[image]

[image]

It's a bit of an art to make it look ecstatically pleasing, but there's lots of resources on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no general rule**

However, here are some concepts and approaches that UX designers use.  You may want to look up these terms to help you think through layout:

- UI or UX layout
- White space or breathing space.
- Grid alignment
- OS guidelines (look for layout metrics for iOS, Android, Windows, for example)

This set of terms should help you get started.